# ElasticSearch: how to use a query result for a new search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've been searching how to use the result of a query to feed a new query in ElasticSearch. I've read that ElasticSearch does not allow inner queries or subqueries but I'm sure there should be a way to do what I've been asked for. I'll show you an example and if someone gives me any advice will be highly appreciated.

This is the log format inserted on ElasticSearch

```
2021-11-04 15:45:51,917 INFO [94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] URL :https://myendpoint.com
2021-11-04 15:45:51,917 INFO [94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] BODY :{"request":{"field1":"value1"},"params":{"param1":1}}
2021-11-04 15:45:51,917 INFO [94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] STATUS:success
2021-11-04 15:45:51,917 INFO [94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] RESULT:{"response":{"field1":"20"},"status":{"code":0,"msg":"OK"}}
2021-11-04 15:45:51,917 INFO [94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] MILLIS:36ms

2021-11-04 18:48:81,917 INFO [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] URL :https://myendpoint.com
2021-11-04 18:48:81,917 INFO [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] BODY :{"request":{"field1":"value1"},"params":{"param1":1}}
2021-11-04 18:48:81,917 INFO [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] STATUS:error
2021-11-04 18:48:81,917 INFO [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] RESULT:Timeout exceeded
2021-11-04 18:48:81,917 INFO [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] MILLIS:3006ms
```

Each row is a different document.
What I'm trying to do is look for a specific URL (https://myendpoint.com in this case), then extract the identifiers associated with the URL ([94648ad9-d5ec-4a48-9cf1-a3f2c2e58cd2] and [744a6299-f7c6-430a-b7ba-e85ab3046237] in this case)
Then search the RESULT associated to those identifiers and classify the results (Timeout, code=0...)

Any tip will be more than welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elastic SQL, that supports subqueries:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-getting-started.html

There are couple of limitations, but in the use case, that you explained, look like you can use it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html#_using_a_sub_select